# PHP While loop of ID's only works with first id

Tags: php, mysql, material-design-lite

I am currently building a lightweight blogging platform with some nice Material Design but i have run into a problem. I have a table with ID's and I want to change the value of public in my table so that you can hide articles from the blog, to do so I made a loop but it only works on the first id and none of the other id's. Here is my code:

```
        try {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                // set public based on the submitted value from your form
                $public = empty($_POST['public'][$row['postID']]) ? 0 : 1;

                // do the update
                $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_posts SET public = ? WHERE postID = ?');
                $stmt->execute(array($public, $row['postID']));
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

If it is of any use [here](http://hastebin.com/epaqahazap.xml) is my full page of PHP, also my fully loaded page can be found [here](http://hastebin.com/apowonilup.xml)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its because afte the first id you directly go to index.php instead you should add another if statement around it to check if each id has been updated

Comment: Where is the index code?

Comment: @SuperDJ this is not the problem, if I remove that link it still doesnt work and my checkboxes dont get updated with the database and on page relaod Ill get asked if I want to resend my form data therefore I have included that redirect

Comment: @Fil what index code do you need/mean?

Comment: this `header('Location: index.php'); `

Comment: @Fil that line is just to reload the page so I dont have to deal with annoyances described in my answer to SuperDJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put this `header('Location: index.php');` outside the while-loop and don't override the `$stmt` instead use another one :

```
//.......
//.......
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    // set public based on the submitted value from your form    
    $public = empty($_POST['public'][$row['postID']]) ? 0 : 1;

    // do the update  
    //Create another statement
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_posts SET public = ? WHERE postID = ?');
    $stmt2->execute(array(
        $public,
        $row['postID']
    ));
}

header('Location: index.php');
//.......
//.......
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this was already suggested by SuperDJ in the comments and it doesnt work, it only makes me click resend on every page load

Comment: Ohh, wait you are overriding the statement inside the loop ;)

Comment: Well that must be it but how do I fix that can I rename my statement or something